# Debug tools in EOS

Tags: nodeos, cleos

What debug tool can print useful readable info when debugging EOS? In the following, I am using Xcode to debug/trace Cleos execution.

```
  auto arg= fc::mutable_variant_object
            ("code", contract_account)
            ("action", action)
            ("args", action_args_var);
  auto result = call(json_to_bin_func, arg);
```

For this part of code, the debugger shows the arg as:

[image]

How to dereference the _data field to get a readable value? Does B1 devs have some lldb data formatters to help debug data structures in EOS?